# Duda con añadir al JPanel una imagen

Tags: java, java-swing, jpanel

Si yo quiero añadir a un panel una imagen sin usar un label,tengo entendido que hay un metodo que es `drawImage`,el cual podria pintar el panel,queria saber si era cierto o no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si, se puede añadir una imagen sin label para ello en la clase que hereda del Canvas tienes que sobreescribir el método `paint` de la siguiente forma:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
  dibujar(img, x, y, g);
}
```

la clase `Graphics` te permite colocar una imágen usando el método `drawImage()`

```
private void dibujar(Img img, int x, int y, Graphics g){
  g.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
}
```

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: gracias y una pregunta,en un jpanel no se puede?

Comment: Si que se puede...mira aquí  lo hacen sobre un JPanel: https://www.driverlandia.com/java-anadir-background-a-jpanel/